# onload event doesn't trigger in chrome until after I click "stop loading this page"

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HMTL page with a select control that lists all the months.  I have added a function to set the default to the current month.  The function is triggered by onload event on the  tag.

I have loaded this page on apache web server installed with XAMPP.  When I load the page with FireFox or Microsoft Edge it works as expected.  When I load it with Chrome it does not.  onload event on chrome doesn't get triggered unless I click on "Stop loading this page".  What am I doing wrong?

Page seems to continue trying to load.  It never stops unless I click the stop page.

Per the suggestion of  Vu Huu Cuong I tried it with chrome incongito mode and it works as expected. Why wouldn't it work with normal mode?!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function populateSelects(){
        var today = new Date();
        var m = today.getMonth();
        document.getElementById('s_month').getElementsByTagName('option')[m].selected = 'selected';
    }

</script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body onload="populateSelects()">

<div > 
    <select id='s_month' name='s_month' >
        <option value="january">January</option>
        <option value="february">February</option>
        <option value="march">March</option>
        <option value="april">April</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="june">June</option>
        <option value="july">July</option>
        <option value="august">August</option>
        <option value="septemeber">Septemeber</option>
        <option value="october">October</option>
        <option value="november">November</option>
        <option value="december">December</option>
    </select>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine on my Chrome, maybe some problems with your Chrome? Did you try in incognito mode?

Comment: just tried it with icognito mode and it works!!!  What does that mean?

Comment: Caching perhaps?

Comment: @afshin Go to `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` and only select `Cached images and files` for the last hour, then clear data. Should work after that

Comment: That didn't do it.  Page continues to try to load and never stops!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with getting this method to work, but what you could do is have the listener in a script tag, instead of in the html. Like this

`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  populateSelects();
});`

Comment: This update worked.  Why would this work but adding the event to <body> tag fail on chrome?!

Comment: I dont know, it seems like a bug in chrome. Other people say it works on their chrome installation, so you could try reinstalling chrome, or checking the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be working fine on chrome. But if the problem persists it's probably because the event has already happened before the JavaScript has been parsed or the listener has been added. In which case you should check if the document has already been loaded before adding the listener.

```
    if (document.readyState === "complete") populateSelects();
    else window.addEventListener("load", populateSelects);
```

Furthermore you could also use the `DOMContentLoaded` event which is triggered when the document has been parsed rather than loaded which is what `load` does.